# Error deploying a nextJS app on github actions

Tags: node.js, github, next.js, github-actions, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my nextJS app on GitHub pages. I'm getting an error at the deploy stage.

My `node.js.yml` file contains the following:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: "npm"
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - run: npm run export
      - run: touch ./out/.nojekyll

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4.2.5
        with:
          branch: gh-pages # The branch the action should deploy to.
          folder: out # The folder the action should deploy.
```

The error code there I get while deploying my repository on another branch is the following :

```
remote: Permission to xxx/xxx.github.io.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxxx.github.io.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Running post deployment cleanup jobs… ️
/usr/bin/git checkout -B github-pages-deploy-action/tpuzb7jkb
Reset branch 'github-pages-deploy-action/tpuzb7jkb'
/usr/bin/chmod -R 777 github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder
/usr/bin/git worktree remove github-pages-deploy-action-temp-deployment-folder --force
Error: The deploy step encountered an error: The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128 ❌
Notice: Deployment failed! ❌
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deploy action needs write access to your repository.

Or upgrade to a newer version of the action, i.e. 4.3.3